# listing npm local modules produces missing errors

Tags: npm

i'm creating new reactjs application using `npx create-react-app my-react`.
everything goes well but when list local modules in `my-react` folder using `npm ls --depth=0` there are some missing errors from npm :

```
    my-react@0.1.0 /tmp/my-react
    ├── react@16.6.3
    ├── react-dom@16.6.3
    └── react-scripts@2.1.1

    npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
    npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
    npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
    npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
    npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
    npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
    npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
    npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
    npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
    npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
    npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
    npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
    npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
    npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
    npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
    npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
    npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
    npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
    npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
    npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
    npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
    npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
    npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
    npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
    npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
    npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by tar@4.4.1
    npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.1
    npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
    npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
    npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
    npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
    npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
    npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by minizlib@1.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this as well, and did some looking. It seems to be an issue with the current way `npm` handles Optional Dependencies. If you do a full `npm list`, you'll find the culprit is `fsevents`.

```
UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@1.2.4
│ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY nan@2.12.1
│ └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
│   ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY detect-libc@1.0.3
│   ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY mkdirp@0.5.1
│   │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY minimist@0.0.8
│   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY needle@2.2.0
│   │ ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY debug@2.6.9
│   │ │ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY ms@2.0.0
│   │ ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY iconv-lite@0.4.21
│   │ │ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY safer-buffer@2.1.2
│   │ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY sax@1.2.4
│   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY nopt@4.0.1
│   │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY abbrev@1.1.1
│   │ └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY osenv@0.1.5
│   │   ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY os-homedir@1.0.2
│   │   └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY os-tmpdir@1.0.2
│   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY npm-packlist@1.1.10
│   │ ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY ignore-walk@3.0.1
│   │ │ └─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY minimatch@3.0.4
│   │ │   └─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY brace-expansion@1.1.11
│   │ │     ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY balanced-match@1.0.0
│   │ │     └── UNMET DEPENDENCY concat-map@0.0.1
│   │ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY npm-bundled@1.0.3
│   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY npmlog@4.1.2
│   │ ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY are-we-there-yet@1.1.4
│   │ │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY delegates@1.0.0
│   │ │ └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY readable-stream@2.3.6
│   │ │   ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY core-util-is@1.0.2
│   │ │   ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3
│   │ │   ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY isarray@1.0.0
│   │ │   ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY process-nextick-args@2.0.0
│   │ │   ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY safe-buffer@5.1.1
│   │ │   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY string_decoder@1.1.1
│   │ │   │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY safe-buffer@5.1.1
│   │ │   └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY util-deprecate@1.0.2
│   │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY console-control-strings@1.1.0
│   │ ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY gauge@2.7.4
│   │ │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY aproba@1.2.0
│   │ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY console-control-strings@1.1.0
│   │ │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY has-unicode@2.0.1
│   │ │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY object-assign@4.1.1
│   │ │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY signal-exit@3.0.2
│   │ │ ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY string-width@1.0.2
│   │ │ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY code-point-at@1.1.0
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY number-is-nan@1.0.1
│   │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY strip-ansi@3.0.1
│   │ │ ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY strip-ansi@3.0.1
│   │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY ansi-regex@2.1.1
│   │ │ └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY wide-align@1.1.2
│   │ │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY string-width@1.0.2
│   │ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY set-blocking@2.0.0
│   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY rc@1.2.7
│   │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY deep-extend@0.5.1
│   │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY ini@1.3.5
│   │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY minimist@1.2.0
│   │ └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY strip-json-comments@2.0.1
│   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY rimraf@2.6.2
│   │ └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY glob@7.1.2
│   │   ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fs.realpath@1.0.0
│   │   ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY inflight@1.0.6
│   │   │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY once@1.4.0
│   │   │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY wrappy@1.0.2
│   │   ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3
│   │   ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY minimatch@3.0.4
│   │   ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY once@1.4.0
│   │   │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY wrappy@1.0.2
│   │   └── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY path-is-absolute@1.0.1
│   ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY semver@5.5.0
│   └─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY tar@4.4.1
│     ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY chownr@1.0.1
│     ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fs-minipass@1.2.5
│     │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY minipass@2.2.4
│     ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY minipass@2.2.4
│     │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY safe-buffer@5.1.1
│     │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY yallist@3.0.2
│     ├─┬ UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY minizlib@1.1.0
│     │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY minipass@2.2.4
│     ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY mkdirp@0.5.1
│     ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY safe-buffer@5.1.1
│     └── UNMET DEPENDENCY yallist@3.0.2
```

`fsevents` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) states that it is only needed for the OS X operating system, so if you're on Linux for example, npm doesn't install it, but then also reports that as an error (?). The behavior is confusing. But it should stay in `package.json` because if someone installs your code on a mac, `fsevents` would be needed.

[There was a PR for this](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/19198) against the `npm` repository to turn the platform dependency logs down to `info`, but it seems to have gotten abandoned when the devs switched npm to a new repo :\

For now, you can safely ignore it (and hopefully get your build system to ignore it as well), or switch to `yarn`.